# Items don't show up in Joomla front-end after manual direct insert into mysqli

Tags: mysql, joomla, import, joomla3.0

I'm trying to manually insert data through phpmyadmin into a joomla 3.x website running on mysqli.
The table I'm trying to update belong to FocalPoint a joomla map component where I need to manually add locations.

After the manual insert, the data correctly show up in the back-end of joomla, but they won't appear on the front-end until I open and save every single item from the back-end.

Any ideas on why they don't automatically appear in the front-end? Do I need to update another table outside the one?

Thank you.

Comment: _Do I need to update another table outside the one_ That would be my guess

Comment: This is probably a good question for the developer @John Pitchers http://stackoverflow.com/users/2260303/john-pitchers

Comment: Most likely you are not using the API correctly.  You should always insert with code and not manually as there are many foreign keys and other items you may need to create and you may need to create data in other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. I had to update another table too in order for the data to be loaded properly.

Thank you all for suggestions